# One UIBarButtonItem with different selectors

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector, uibarbuttonitem

I want to create one `UIBarButtonItem` for navigation right button item with two selectors. When the `UITableView` enters editing mode the right button item has the title "Favorite All" with the (favAll) selector and when one row in the table view is selected this button title should be "favorite" with the (faveSome) selector?

How can you create one UIBarButtonItem with two titles and selectors?

Comment: You can only have one selector. Use a flag to determine what to do when the button is tapped.

Comment: Don't create one, create two, keep "Fav All" as default, but after selecting one row, set "Favorite" as right button.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, this is **not** good practice.

Instead, on the action you can determine what logic it should be doing for Edit mode / Normal mode.

Something like;

```
@selector(edit:)

    - (IBAction)edit:(id)sender {
      if (self.isEditing) {

      }
    }
```